# Spring Integration @MessagingGateway multiple replies for a single request

Tags: spring, tcp, spring-integration

I am trying to create an application able to subscribe to external legacy/non-spring server, with the use of Spring Integration. I am using both `AbstractServerConnectionFactory` and `AbstractClientConnectionFactory`. The problem is that after I send the message which enables subscription I receive more than one reply (one ack for subscription, then a message every x minutes containing subscription data), for a single request. It seems like `@Gateway` is not suitable for such case, so I tried to somehow redirect the replies to `@MessageEndpoint` by setting the request channel on `TcpInboudGateway` and reply channel `TcpOutboundGateway` to be the same. This did not help and I can not get rid of *TcpOutboundGateway Cannot corelate response - no pending reply for ...*. I tried to remove `CachingClientConnectionFactory` and use pure `AbstractClientConnectionFactory`, but it also did not help. Every single request and single response calls are working fine. Also, I am able to send any packets to my app and they are handled just fine.

Tried to solve this for many days, but I am still stuck with it. After all this time I assume it must be the problem with `@MessagingGateway` and `@Gateway` methods within it not being able to handle more than one reply, nor delegating it to `@MessageEndpoint`. Is there any way to get rid of `@MessagingGateway` and using something capable of doing mentioned operation? Maybe there is a way of using `@Header` to free the `@Gateway` methods for handling any replies? Searched in Spring Integration samples on github and in the documnetation, but did not find answers for those questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Gateways are specifically designed for 1 request/1 reply messaging.

To achieve arbitrary bi-directional messaging between client and server, you can use a pair of [Collaborating Channel Adapters](https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/5.3.0.RELEASE/reference/html/ip.html#ip-collaborating-adapters).

> ... You can also use collaborating adapters (server-side or client-side) for totally asynchronous communication (rather than with request-reply semantics). On the server side, message correlation is automatically handled by the adapters, because the inbound adapter adds a header that allows the outbound adapter to determine which connection to use when sending the reply message. ...

Comment: I undestand now that the only way to achieve multiple replies is to avoid Gateways. However this way I don't have any method to invoke, in order to pass data (byte array) to a channel. I have checked the https://github.com/garyrussell/spring-integration-samples/tree/master/intermediate/tcp-client-server-multiplex for a solution. However I have only found xml based configuration. Also there is also this little schema attached: 
gateway -> outbound-channel-adapter |-> aggregator and it clearly contains a gateway. I am confused. Is there any java implementation without gateway, available online?

Comment: If you read the link I pointed you too; collaborating adapters can be used to solve several problems; that sample is still request/reply, but multiple in-process requests can happen concurrently. As the link says, `You can also use collaborating adapters (server-side or client-side) for totally asynchronous communication (rather than with request-reply semantics).` I will try to find some time to create a new sample.

Comment: Pull request for new sample [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-samples/pull/283).

Comment: Thanks! I am unfortunately limited by the Spring Integration version 4.3.7.RELEASE, so I can not use ```IntegrationFlow``` and ```IntegrationFlows```. I examined the code You have written and to my understanding I should use ```TcpReceivingChannelAdapter``` and use ```setOutputChannel``` method, so it points to channel (transformer) I want.```TcpSendingMessageHandler``` should be ```@Autowire```d to my ```@MessageEndpoint```, so I can use ```handleMessageInternal``` to send the payload wrapped by ```Message<byte[]>``` as payload, with empty headers. Am I completely wrong, or is it alright?

Comment: 4.3.7 is over 3 years old; you should at least upgrade to 4.3.22. There is a stand-alone `spring-integration-java-dsl` for `IntegrationFlow` with 4.3.x. If you don't want to use that, don't call `handleMessageInternal()` directly. Instead add `@ServiceActivator` to the `TcpSendingMessageHandler` `@Bean` and send a message to its `inputChannel`. 4.3.x will not be supported after the end of the year.

Comment: I have swapped the ```TcpOutboundGateway``` with ```TcpSendingMessageHandler``` and left the annotations unchanged. I still use the class annotated with ```@MessagingGateway``` and method with ```@Gateway``` to pass the payload to ```TcpSendingMessageHandler``` channel. Even though I was not able to use Yours solution it helped me a lot. I was thinking about creating ```TcpOutboundGateway``` for handling request-reply operations and let adapters handle other operations, but ```TcpNetClientConnectionsFactory``` cannot be shared. Creating two CF does not work, but thats another topic. Thank you!